# Implement a lists:map using case clauses instead of function clauses in Erlang

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, erlang-shell, erlang-supervisor

Can anyone tell me what this means? I am new to this and my friend recommended me to post in this website.
By the way I'm new to Erlang.

If possible I want to write a code in editor and I don't even understand the question any sample input/output and how it works an explanation will do. Thankyou

Comment: First step to solving a problem starts at `understanding the problem`.  If you do not understand the problem, I suggest you ask back your friend to explain it in little more detail or with more clarity. Ask back questions if you have to, and try to understand the problem as the very first thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example showing how to use function clauses, then case statements to do the same thing.  Put the following code in a file named `a.erl` in some directory:

```
-module(a).
-export([show_stuff/1, show_it/1]).

show_stuff(1) ->
    io:format("The argument was 1~n");
show_stuff(2) ->
    io:format("The argument was 2~n");
show_stuff(_)->
    io:format("The argument was something other than 1 or 2~n").

show_it(X) ->
    case X of
        1 -> io:format("The argument was 1~n");
        2 -> io:format("The argument was 2~n");
        _ -> io:format("The argument was something other than 1 or 2~n")
    end.
```

Note that the file name, `a.erl` and the module directive:

```
-module(a).
```

must match.  So, if you named your file `homework1.erl`, then the module directive in the file must be:

```
-module(homework1).
```

To save a lot of typing, it's best to use very short module names (as you will see below).

In a terminal window, switch directories to the directory containing `a.erl`:

```
 ~$ cd erlang_programs/
```

then launch the erlang shell:

```
 ~/erlang_programs$ erl
Erlang/OTP 24 [erts-12.0.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:1]

Eshell V12.0.2  (abort with ^G)
```

Next, execute the following statements:

```
1> c(a).   <--- Compiles the code in your file 
{ok,a}     <--- Or, you may get errors which must be corrected, then try recompiling.

2> a:show_stuff(1).
The argument was 1
ok

3> a:show_stuff(4).
The argument was something other than 1 or 2
ok

4> a:show_it(1).
The argument was 1
ok

5> a:show_it(4).
The argument was something other than 1 or 2
ok

6>
```

Note the syntax for calling a function defined in a file/module:

```
 module_name:function_name(arg1, arg2, ... argn).
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that the question refers to the implementation of `lists:map/2`, a function that applies the same function (received as a parameter) to all elements of a list and returns the resulting list.

In other words, [this function](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#map-2).

You can check the [OTP Github repo](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/b4f57a1db7cf62918f17e1772206c9cd71acce00/lib/stdlib/src/lists.erl#L1306-L1322) to see how that function is implemented:

```erlang
map(F, List) when is_function(F, 1) ->
    case List of
        [Hd | Tail] -> [F(Hd) | map_1(F, Tail)];
        [] -> []
    end.

map_1(F, [Hd | Tail]) ->
    [F(Hd) | map_1(F, Tail)];
map_1(_F, []) ->
    [].
```

Or you can conceive an even *simpler* implementation, as…

```erlang
map(F, []) -> [];
map(F, [H|T]) -> [F(H) | map(F, T)].
```

Both of them (for the OTP version, I'm referring to `map_1/2`) use pattern-matching in function clause heads to distinguish between the base case and the recursive step of the function.

The request that you received is to implement the same algorithm using a single function clause with a `case` clause instead of the two function clauses you see above.

Comment: But why are we givin two arguments such as F, List and can that have to be an input which we have to give then what is the exact input to be given.

Comment: I don't understand your question, but I hope that other answers in this thread do solve it.

Answer (score 1):

> any sample input/output and how it works an explanation will do

In the documentaion linked in Brujo Benavides's answer, you can see:

> > Takes a function from As to Bs, and a list of As and produces a list of Bs by applying the function to every element in the list. This function is used to obtain the return values.

So `F` is a function (of a single argument) such as `fun(X) -> X*2 end`. See https://www.erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/funs.html#syntax-of-funs or https://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#funs to understand `fun` expressions. `List1` is a list of values which the function `F` can work on (in this case numbers) such as `[1,2,3]`. Then `list:map(fun(X) -> X*2 end, [1,2,3])` calls `fun(X) -> X*2 end` on each element of list `[1,2,3]` and returns the list of return values `[2,4,6]`. Your function should give the same result on these arguments.